# How create cookies in browser with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, session, cookies

I have a function authenticate of users in node js, and I'm not using an authentication, passport or other lib, I couldn't understand it well, so I did my own authentication function.
However, my function is only authentic for users, it does not create cookies, I need to create cookies on a "expiration date" node, and that as soon as it waits, it redirects me back to the login route.  I want to implement this in this function:

```
function verify(req,res,username,password){                   
 db.serialize(function (){                                      
 const query = 'SELECT * from Users WHERE User = (?) AND Password = (?)'
 db.all(query,[username, password],function(err,rows){
 if(err) {
  console.log(err);
 }
 if(rows.length == 1){
  console.log(rows);                                            
  console.log("Correct user");
  res.render(__dirname + "/View/Home/index.handlebars");
 }                                                             
 else{
  console.log("Incorrecto user!")
  res.redirect('/login')
 }
});
});
}
```

This is my route in node js

```
app.get("/login", (req,res) => {                               
 res.render(__dirname + "/View/Home/login.handlebars");       
});

app.post("/",(req,res) => {                                    
 const username = req.body.username                          
 const password = req.body.password
 verify(req,res,username,password)

});
```

**I need to create a cookie within the verify () function if the user is valid and when the cookie expires the user is redirected to the "/ login" route again**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Express server, you can set cookies using [`res.cookie(name, value, options)`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.cookie). `options` is an object, and the `maxAge` property is probably what you want, which is a number is miliseconds before it expires. For example, if the user is valid you could do `res.cookie('username', username, {maxAge: 172800000 /* two days */})`.

You can access the request's cookies with [`req.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.cookies), which is an object of cookie name keys and string values. You can check if the `'username'` key exists and is valid, and if not, redirect using [`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.redirect).

```
function verify(req,res,username,password){
 // Place this block wherever you want it to check for a valid cookie
 // Depending on the context when this function is called, that might not be at the start
 if(typeof(req.cookies.username) != 'string')
   res.redirect('/login');     

 db.serialize(function (){                                      
 const query = 'SELECT * from Users WHERE User = (?) AND Password = (?)'
 db.all(query,[username, password],function(err,rows){
 if(err) {
  console.log(err);
 }
 if(rows.length == 1){
  console.log(rows);                                            
  console.log("Correct user");
  // Set Cookie
  res.cookie('username', username, {maxAge: 172800000 /* two days */});
  res.render(__dirname + "/View/Home/index.handlebars");
 }                                                             
 else{
  console.log("Incorrecto user!")
  res.redirect('/login')
 }
});
});
}
```

Comment: yes I am using express, could you give me an example with my code because I had used cookies before but I think I didn’t do it the right way because it didn’t work, it didn’t make an error anymore it’s like I didn’t create the cookie.

Comment: @Jessica Edited.

Comment: I have the following error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: I believe your code is what I need, but I need to check if the cookie exists every few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Keycloak**

***Download***
[Offical Keycloak Download Page](https://www.keycloak.org/downloads)

**Install For Linux/Unix**

```
./bin/standalone.sh
```

** Install For Windows**

```
\bin\standalone.bat
```

Use arg -b to Bind network address (default is 127.0.0.1) like so

```
./bin/standalone.sh -b 192.168.1.150
```

**Install Keycloak-nodejs-connect**

```
npm install keycloak-connect
```

[Official Node.js Example from Github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/master/example/index.js)

**Reference: [Getting Started Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/)**

Comment: i spent about 8 hours in total reading the documentation, and i couldn't use passport in my code because i'm using sqlite, i found a code and it wasn't quite what i needed, in the end i couldn't find what i needed and i couldn't get out of place. So I did this function because after 1 million attempts I had to do it another way. :(

Comment: @Jessica You are right! Passport Documentation isn't that useful, missing a lot of things. To be honest I switched to Kaycloak. Very friendly UI, Backend and Frontend as well ! Deep control, Logs like everything except your app. You can have 3rd party identity providers Google, Github, Twitter...etc You'll be impressed how things can go easily using Keycloak and Node.js you just do `app.get('/login', keycloak.protect(), function (req, res) {` and if he/she/it none authenticated users must redirected to your Single Sign-on server thanks to token, cookies, and third party like dozens of dem

Comment: It has everything you need from authentication, authorization to be authenticated =) Happy surfing !

Comment: The logins of registered users are in sqlite, and I searched and did not find much content in this library :(

Comment: Authentication has become a very complex thing in my head lol

Comment: Keycloak is your key for getting authentication away from your head. Like once and for all =)